# .NET MAUI docs for SQLite say to temporarily install Nuget package: why?

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui, nuget-package

In the [Maui docs for SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite), it says to install two Nuget packages:
**[sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/)**
**[SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green/)**

In the description for the second Nuget package *SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green*, it says:

> In addition to **sqlite-net-pcl**, you *temporarily* need to install the underlying dependency that exposts SQLite on each platform... *continues with metadata about the package*

It doesn't say anything about this cryptic message for the rest of the document (as far as I can tell).

What does this mean? Should I install the package, build the project, and uninstall it?  If so, why?  Is "exposing SQLite" a thing that only happens once?

---

EDIT: it turns out I was adding more meaning to the cryptic message than is necessary.

Here's what the statement means:

> We need this second Nuget package because it does some things that the first package doesn't do; hopefully adding the second package will be a temporary fix, as we hope to soon add the thing that the second package does to the first package, making the second package unnecessary.

Comment: https://medium.com/@taublast/entity-framework-with-code-first-migrations-in-net-maui-3efbdb765592

Comment: Someone edited my terrible jokes away!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine this might be a bit unclear if you're not familiar with the material. Keeping in mind that even the docs are open-source, I went to look for some more information and found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/1637).

From that it seems that there was an issue amongst these packages that caused the need to install the `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green` package. The explanation from the linked issue:

> The issue is this. sqlite-net-pcl has a dependency of SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green >= 2.04. But for SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green to work with .NET MAUI, you need >= 2.1.0. Once sqlite-net-pcl gets a new release that specifies the correct version for the dependency, there'll be no need to install SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green yourself.

It seems that the `sqlite-net-pcl` package has not seen any updates in a while, and maybe we never will, so for the time being you can assume that you need the `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green` package in order for this to function properly.

As for the exposing part, that is a way of saying that this package is used to enable the SQLite functionality on each platform. This plugin *exposes* the SQLite programming surface to .NET MAUI if you will.

So no, that is not a thing that happens once. The exposing (and thus availability of SQLite) is turned on or off by installing the `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green` package at this point in time.

Comment: Thank you sir!  That makes perfect sense.  And here I am, adding more meaning to the "temporary install" comment than is necessary.  This is how conspiracy theories start.